# How to handle mouseover events in GTK+3?

Tags: c, gtk3

I was wondering how to handle mouse over events without having one of the mouse buttons pressed.

I wrote the following code (based on Cairo Zetcode tutorial), that draws and updates a line while the mouse button is pressed and the cursor is moving around:

```
#include <cairo.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>


static void do_drawing(cairo_t *);

struct {
    double coordx[2];
    double coordy[2];
}glob;

static gboolean on_draw_event(GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, gpointer user_data)
{
    do_drawing(cr);  
    return FALSE;
}

static void do_drawing(cairo_t *cr)
{
    cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 0, 0, 0);
    cairo_set_line_width(cr, 0.8);

    cairo_move_to(cr, glob.coordx[0], glob.coordy[0]);
    cairo_line_to(cr, glob.coordx[1], glob.coordy[1]);

    cairo_stroke(cr);    
}

static gboolean clicked(GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventButton *event, gpointer user_data)
{
    if (event->button == 1) {
        glob.coordx[0] = event->x;
        glob.coordy[0] = event->y;
    }

    if (event->button == 3) {
        glob.coordx[0] = event->x;
        glob.coordy[0] = event->y;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

static gboolean motion_notify_event( GtkWidget *widget, GdkEventMotion *event ) {

    glob.coordx[1] = event->x;
    glob.coordy[1] = event->y;
    gtk_widget_queue_draw(widget);

    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *darea;

  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

  window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

  darea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), darea);

  gtk_widget_add_events(window, GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK);

  g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(darea), "draw", G_CALLBACK(on_draw_event), NULL); 

  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);  

  g_signal_connect(window, "button-press-event", G_CALLBACK(clicked), NULL);

  g_signal_connect (window, "motion_notify_event",G_CALLBACK(motion_notify_event), NULL);


  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window), GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER);
  gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window), 400, 300); 
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Lines");

  gtk_widget_show_all(window);

  gtk_main();

  return 0;
}
```

How do I get GTK to update the drawing of the line just by moving the mouse, i.e. without having to press the mouse button?

THanks!

Comment: Does the `motion_notify_event` function get called?

Comment: Yes, it gets called otherwise the program would not update the line drawing

Comment: So what's the exact problem? Right now you are handling mouse events. If you want to draw without mouse clicks, make an additional surface, update it in `motion_notify_event` and use `cairo_set_source_surface` to draw from this surface in `on_draw_event`

Comment: why do i need to make an additional surface to draw without mouse clicks?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was irrelevant. You have added only `GDK_BUTTON_PRESS_MASK`. You also need `GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK`